# google plus integration(signin) in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I want to implement google plus implementation in my website using cold fusion.but I searched on google but I am not getting any proper answer.please give me any link.
I found 'cfoauth' tag but this tag not working.

### **Edit:**

finally I am getting this code

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer>

<script>
    function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
          alert(authResult['access_token']);
          // Signed in with Google+, you can proceed as usual
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
          // There was an error signing the user in
          alert('comes here 22');
        }
    }
</script>

<span id="signinButton">
    <span class="g-signin"
        data-callback="signinCallback"
        data-clientid="+++++++++************************//////"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
    </span>
</span>
```

but whenever signin button click another window open and login.after that window closed.now I want take that user values like email,googleid...how get those values  please help me.

Comment: Which version of CF you are using?

Comment: @Pankaj   please find edited code,